# DataTable is autoadjusting the height of the row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used DataTable before, but right now I'm facing odd issue. I have a DataTable and there is 1 row in it. It looks like for some reason the height of the header and height of the first row in the tbody are getting quite big and when inspecting the elements, it looks like their height is 250px and above. When there are more rows added in the table body - the height of row is being reduced and when I have 10 rows, the height of each row is 37px.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
    var firstTable;
    var secondTable;
    var approvedTable;
    var declinedTable;

    var settings = {
        order: [
            [1, 'asc'],  
        ],
        orderMulti: true,
        lengthMenu: [
            [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
        ],
        pageLength: 10
    }


    firstTable = new DataTable('#approve-first-table', settings);
    secondTable = new DataTable('#second-approve-table', settings);
    approvedTable = new DataTable('#approved-table', settings);
    declinedTable = new DataTable('#declined-table', settings);
```

How can I disable the autoadjusting of the height of the rows?